# like '%%' have more then result

Tags: oracle

I have the following table:

```
number | desc
1      | name
2      | pake
3      | name
4      | fly
5      | high
```

I'm using the `'like'` keyword, but I want it to have more than 1 comparison

If I write query below, I'll get number 1 and 3:

```
select number  from mytable where desc like'%name%'
```

I want to use several conditions for my `desc` column, this is what I have so far:

```
select number from mytable where desc like'%name%' and like'%fly%'
```

This will cause an error. Is there a something similar to what I'm trying?

Will nesting select do the trick ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

repeat targetted field name

```
select number 
from mytable 
where desc like '%name%' 
or desc like '%fly%'
```

maybe and, maybe or, maybe.

Comment: ah I forget the name of the column thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
select number from mytable where desc like'%name%' or desc like'%fly%'
```